# Hi, Unable to install python in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, ubuntu-19.10

[image: While trying to download the python package in ubuntu 19.10, got this error. Tried sudo apt-get update, but of no use. How can I install the python in ubuntu server]

While trying the download python package in ubuntu 19.10, got this error. Tried sudo apt-get update, but of no use. How can I install the python in ubuntu server

Comment: how did u get ubuntu 19? i saw only 16, 18, then 20

Comment: Google works wonders: https://askubuntu.com/questions/865554/how-do-i-install-python-3-6-using-apt-get

Comment: Non-LTS releases (all except {even number}.04) of Ubuntu have a very short support time. More than a year later you should update to 20.04 to get software and updates.

Comment: *Why* do you want to install Python 3.6, specifically? It’s not the most recent version. Furthermore, as Klaus said, you shouldn’t be running on Ubuntu 19.10. Update your system, *then* install an up-to-date Python (or whichever version you need).

Comment: I tried to install other python versions as well, However I have the same issue. The screenshot attached is for reference. Since I had issues with PIP package, i have removed the PIP and python to reinstall it

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.6+ should be available by default on Ubuntu 18+, thus find out which Python version is available as listed in package repo files first:

```sh
sudo apt search --names-only "^python3\."
```

See the results and choose 1 of them to install:

```sh
sudo apt install python3.6 # Or 3.7 3.8 3.9, etc
```

Comment: tried the mentioned commands, but the error is same.

Answer (score 0):

To install python:

```sh
sudo apt-get install python3
```

But Ubuntu already comes with python, so you just use `python3`.
Note that in Ubuntu you always must specify the version 3. To execute a file, run:

```sh
python3 file.py
```

EDIT:

To install python 3.6 specifically, execute:

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

Comment: Will this always install Python 3.6?

Comment: This will install the latest version of python in the repository. If you want to deal with different versions of python, you should use anaconda or something similar to create virtual environments.

Comment: I mean, OP wants Python 3.6 specifically, but this answer currently suggests to install the latest version, which may not be 3.6

Comment: I have updated the answer, you must add a ppa

Comment: Error: sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found, tried using sudo apt-get install software-properties-common, got the below error:The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 Depends: python3 but it is not going to be installed